# Test event handler of InputFile in Blazor component with bUnit

Tags: c#, blazor, bunit

I have a Blazor component like this:

```cs
// MyComponent.razor

<InputFile id="input-file" OnChange="@LoadImage" accept=".jpg,.jpeg,.png"/>

@code {
    internal IBrowserFile? File;

    private void LoadImage(InputFileChangeEventArgs args) => File = args.File;
}
```

I want to test the event handler of this component using bUnit with the following test:

```cs
[Test]
public void UploadFile()
{
    // Arrange
    var browserFile = new Mock<IBrowserFile>().Object;
    var ctx = new TestContext();
    var testee = ctx.RenderComponent<MyComponent>

    // Act
    testee.Find("[id^=\"input-file\"]").Change(new InputFileChangeEventArgs(new []{browserFile}));

    // Assert
    testee.Instance.File.Should().Be(browserFile);
}
```

This test fails with the following error:

```
Bunit.MissingEventHandlerException : The element does not have an event handler for the event 'onchange', nor any other events.
   at Bunit.TriggerEventDispatchExtensions.TriggerNonBubblingEventAsync(ITestRenderer renderer, IElement element, String eventName, EventArgs eventArgs) in /_/src/bunit.web/EventDispatchExtensions/TriggerEventDispatchExtensions.cs:line 144
   at Bunit.InputEventDispatchExtensions.ChangeAsync(IElement element, ChangeEventArgs eventArgs) in /_/src/bunit.web/EventDispatchExtensions/InputEventDispatchExtensions.cs:line 36
   at Bunit.InputEventDispatchExtensions.Change[T](IElement element, T value) in /_/src/bunit.web/EventDispatchExtensions/InputEventDispatchExtensions.cs:line 18
```

So how can I trigger Blazor's `OnChange` event of an `InputFile`?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is full documented at [Testing components that uses the  component](https://github.com/bUnit-dev/bUnit/discussions/415) discussion, invoke `OnChange` on component. In your code:

```cs
var testee = ctx.RenderComponent<MyComponent>();

var filesToUpload = new InputFileChangeEventArgs(new []{browserFile});
var inputComponent = testee.FindComponent<InputFile>().Instance;

// Invoke the OnChange event callback to emulate the
// user uploading one or more files
await cut.InvokeAsync(() => 
    inputComponent.OnChange.InvokeAsync(filesToUpload));

// ...
```

**Important part:**

To work with `InputFile` you must to setup your `JSInterop`. Use a `TestContext` class instead to create your context by hand (avoid this: `ctx = new TestContext();` ):

```cs
    public class FileUpload1Test : TestContext
    {
        public FileUpload1Test()
        {
            // FileInput component configuration
            Services.AddSingleton(Options.Create(new RemoteBrowserFileStreamOptions()));
            JSInterop.SetupVoid(invocation => invocation.Identifier == "Blazor._internal.InputFile.init")
                .SetVoidResult();
        }
```

Comment: Thank you! Maybe it's worth being mentioned [here](https://bunit.dev/docs/interaction/trigger-event-handlers.html?tabs=csharp)?

Comment: @mu88, sure. Or in a special topic "how to invoke custom EventCallback". Any case, bunit is awesome.